# how to populate a CreateView field based on count of model instances in Django

Tags: python, django, count, instance

I have a model for players on a ladder.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    # Availability choice list
    available = 'AVL'
    injured = 'INJ'
    away = 'AWY'
    retired = 'RET'
    AVAILABILITY_CHOICES = [
        (available, 'available'),
        (injured, 'injured'),
        (away, 'out of town'),
        (retired, 'retired')
    ]

    # Player fields
    first = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30)
    last = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30)
    cell = models.CharField('Cell Phone', max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField('Email') # changed field type
    availability = models.CharField('Availability', choices = AVAILABILITY_CHOICES, \
                                     max_length = 15, default='AVL')
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default = 99)
```

I am also using a CreateView to create a new player.

```
class PlayerCreateView(CreateView):
    model =Player
    num_players = Player.objects.all().count()
    print('There are {} players'.format(num_players))
    context_object_name = 'player'
    fields = ['ranking', 'first', 'last', 'cell', 'email', 'availability']
    template_name = 'player_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('players')
```

I can't believe I'm asking this (still new to Django) but I haven't found a way to pre-populate the player's ranking field. So basically I need to count the number of existing players and populate the ranking field. It can't be based on ID because some players may have been deleted.

In the model I tried using a variable for the default, but Django threw a fit. (NameError: name 'Player' is not defined) ... evidently because you can't reference Player within the class definition of Player.

There must be a "djangonista" way of doing this simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can prepopulate the form in the create view by overriding [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial):

```
class PlayerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Player
    # ...

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial["ranking"] = Player.objects.count()  # whatever formula
        return initial
```

If you want a dynamic default value in the model you can specify a [callable as default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default):

```
def default_ranking():
    return Player.objects.count()

class Player(models.Model):
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=default_ranking)  # no parentheses!
```

This will not fill the form field, however, but only come into effect if an instance is saved without a ranking value.

Comment: Thank you! I will try these approaches and see which works best.

Comment: Although both methods seem to be able to come up with a count value, for some reason, the count() method is returning one too few players. The new person should have a ranking of "count + 1" (16 if there are 15 players already on the ladder), but to get the correct value on the form I apparently need to specify count + 2. Any idea why Django's count would be out of sync with the actual number of players? (BTW, the # no parentheses comment was extremely helpful. I would not have anticipated that.)